# AngularJS ng-repeat not working for object

Tags: angularjs, dictionary, key-value, angularjs-ng-repeat

According to the documentation and other SO questions, I should be able to output a set of key/value pairs with `ng-repeat`

```
$scope.getFilters = function(){

    return {
        film : true,
        game : true,
        music : true,
        sport : true,
        tv : true
    }
}
$scope.filters = $scope.getFilters();
```

Then this is my HTML

```
        {{filters}}
        <div 
            ng-repeat="(name,set) in filters"
        >
            {{name}} : {{set}}
        </div>
```

But this is all I get from that:

```
{"film":true,"game":true,"music":true,"sport":true,"tv":true}
<!-- ngRepeat: (name,set) in filters -->
```

I've tried JS fiddles, it works. This is only a snippet of my code, there is more on the page but I can't paste it all here.

**UPDATE**: Just noticed this error:

```
Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: (name,set) in filters key: boolean:true
```

Comment: Ok - obvious now, found the error elsewhere on SO thanks to the console.log I added. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in [1,1,1] track by $index">
```

Check out this question for more details...[Angular ng-repeat Error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed)

Hope this helps!