# Duplicates not allowed in Repeater in production ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, the following works when I run it on a local server:

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="TheController">
    <ul id="grid" class="grid">
        <li ng-repeat="guy in info">
            <a href="#">
                <img ng-src="{{ guy.img }}" alt="{{ guy.name }}">
                <p class="guy-name">{{ guy.name }}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**js** -- and I'm doing something like this in my controller:

```
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.info = data;
        });
```

**data**

```
[
  {
    "img":"someImg.jpg",
    "name":"Paul Saul",
    "title":"Boss"
  },
  {
    "img":"anotherImg.jpg",
    "name":"Karalyn",
    "title":"Web"
  },
  {
    "img":"img.jpg",
    "name":"Derp",
    "title":"Retail"
  }
]
```

But when I run it in production I get a ngRepeat:dupes error. Any ideas why? I've tried to `add track by $index` as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) and the error goes away but doesn't render the data and infinitely creates blank DOM nodes. Already read through the [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977103/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-on-ng-repeat?lq=1) on SO, but can't seem to figure this out. I repeat, the above works locally with no errors; live it throws the error.

Comment: When you change scope's variables with async ways(i think $http is async) you need to use `$scope.apply()` after all assignments. You can try to use **apply** method.

Comment: trying $scope.$apply() just throws an [inprog error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest)

Comment: I would look at what your production server is returning.  It sounds like it might be returning an array of [undefined, undefined] or [null, null] or similar.  Just point your browser to http://productionserver/data.json to verify that the data being sent down is valid.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, the data was being blocked by the server. So, there's that, which is nice.

Comment: Been there, done that!