# ng-repeat embedded in a directive - gives dupes error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code structure:

chart-item is a directive that gets passed an array (item.colors), inside the directive is another sub directive that displays a dialog for each chart-item when user clicks on the chart.

issue is dupes error on the colors array.. i've tried 'track by $id(colors.label) and track by $index but still get the dupes error, there can be 'n' rows with 'n' charts on each row.

any suggestions on how to get rid of the dups errors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the actual error? "dupes error" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: can you show the data. nobody can help without looking at your code & data

Comment: Maybe related to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed