# OnsenUI List and ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I wrote a simple ng-repeat example using Onsen-UI, it works great (see my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/ogWwdY)) but it doesn't work when I add more variable in `var city`

**Update #1**

**JS**

```
    var city=[...'Kumbakonam','Kumily']; //Works
```

but if i add more variables, like

```
var city=[...'Kumbakonam','Kumily','city','city','city','city','city','city','city','city','city','city','city']; //Not Works
```

[Codepen that works](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/ogWwdY)

[Codepen that doesn't](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/pvPwZY)

Am i missing something or is it a limitation or something like that. Please explain.

Thank you guys.

Comment: What do you mean by add more variable in var city? Can you showcase the issue in codepen. In this fork click on add and it will add the item.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEmjyN

Comment: Thanks @PSL for the response. I have edited my question, See Update #1. and yes, your codepen works but i need it to be static, initialise it first and then display the result.

Comment: That is because you have duplicates in ng-repeat, you should wither use array of objects or use track by $index. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbjOgY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat Error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed)

Comment: It works. Simple mistake learned today. Thanks @psl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the console while developing. It shows what's wrong:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: list in cityList, Duplicate key: string:City, Duplicate value: "City"
```

You aren't allowed to repeat values in the `ngRepeat` directive.