# Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a similar situation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed) but I use a $http call to get my data to build a infinite scrolling table,
and get:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: i in items, Duplicate key: string:b, Duplicate value: b
```

source code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/2829/)

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/) is the source code that i followed and it worked

i need help in this situation!

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate Items in the array, If you want to ignore use **`track by $index`**

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items track by $index">{{i.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a few issues in your jsFiddle. As noted above by @Manjesh V, you need to add `track by $index`, giving you:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items track by $index">{{i.name}}</li>
```

Also, as mentioned by @sMr, you need to add `$http` module to the directive.

Finally, your jsFiddle links to a really old version of AngularJS, v1.0.0. You can add 1.2.1 and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be you have not passed the `$http` module to your main controller.

```
function Main($scope,$http) {
    $scope.items = [];

        $scope.loadMore = function() {
        $http.get('/echo/json').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                    $scope.items += data;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    console.log("call failed");
                });
    };
    $scope.loadMore();
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vks2znkz/)