# Duplicate in ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello for some reason it says as a error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: mes in messagess, Duplicate key: string:f, Duplicate value: f

But i dont understand why, i personally dont see any duplicates...

[Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/chattapp) is my Cloud9 File to see the code and make changes...

Here is my Chat.html:

```
<h1 style = "text-align:center; position:relative; left:-80px"> Universal Chat </h1>


<div id = "rectangle" >
      <ul id="example-messages" class="example-chat-messages">
        <li ng-repeat = "mes in messagess">
            {{mes}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="chatbox" rows="1" ng-model = "textValue">

  </textarea>
  <a class="btn right" id = "submitButton" ng-click = "submit()">
       <span class="left title">Submit Comment</span>
       <span class="right icon icon-comment"><span class="slant-right"></span></span>
     </a>
```

And my chatController.js:

```
app.controller('chatController', ["$scope", 'AuthService', "Auth", "Ref", "$rootScope", "$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject",
    function($scope, AuthService, Auth, Ref, $rootScope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
        var postsArray = {}
        console.log(AuthService.User.email) //Gives me correct Email
        console.log(AuthService.User.password) //Gives me correct password
        console.log(AuthService.User.uid) //Gives me correct uid
        console.log(AuthService.User.username) //Gives me correct username
        some = $firebaseArray(Ref.child("Posts").child(AuthService.User.username));
        console.log((some))
        var postsFirebase = $firebaseObject(Ref)
        var username = AuthService.User.username
$scope.messagess = {}
        $scope.submit = function() {
            if (!($scope.textValue)) {

            }
            else {

                some.$add({
                    Posts: $scope.textValue
                }).then(function(authData) {
                    console.log(authData.path)
                    Ref.child("Posts").child(username).child(authData.path.o[2]).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                        console.log(snapshot.val().Posts)

                           $scope.messagess.push(snapshot.val().Posts)
                           snapshot.val().Posts

                    }, function(errorObject) {
                        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
                    });


                }).catch(function(errorObject){
                    alert("See the console for more details")
                    console.error(errorObject.code)
                })

            }

        }
    }
])
```

SnapShot.val is like the current post you submitted in my firebase here:

[image]
This is not a duplicate. Those methods from other places didnt work..

Comment: Its not a duplicate of that. I already tried that and did my no help... @fracz

Comment: Are you sure the `messages` is an array? The duplicate error says its `f` duplicated, so maybe the `messages` is a string, not an array?

Comment: Yea messages is a string.. Whats wrong?  @fracz

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate error says its `f` duplicated, so I suppose the messages is a string, not an array. What you are trying to do is to display every message. But now, you are iterating over the message itself, that is:

```
<li ng-repeat="mes in 'message'">
```

Which takes `m` for the first item, `e` for second, `s` fot the third. And, as you may suppose, it will throws the error when it notices the next (duplicated) `s`.

You should iterate over array of messages, i.e.:

```
<li ng-repeat="mes in ['message']">
```

Which will display them correctly. Please review what is saved to the scope in this line:

```
$scope.messagess = snapshot.val().Posts
```

It should be an array.

However, please note that after fixing it you should still use the `track by` as posting the same message twice will tirgger the error again.

```
<li ng-repeat="mes in messages track by $index">
```

Related: [Angular ng-repeat Error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed)]

If you still have the problem, please try to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

---

UPDATE:

Based on the screen of data structure you provided (the `Posts` is string as I supposed), you should change the scope assignment to:

```
$scope.messagess = snapshot.val()
```

and then, in the view, read all values, i.e.

```
<li ng-repeat="mes in messages">{{ mes.Posts }}</li>
```

However, I find this structure (and naming) weird.

Comment: Still says same error...  You can see my cloud9 file for more details. I changed my li line to yours..

Comment: How do i make it an array. that includes all posts. That is what im stumbled on...

Comment: What is an example content of the `snapshot.val().Posts`?

Comment: I tried to push it but it says Uncaught TypeError: $scope.messagess.push  I will update the anwser.

Comment: Edited. snapshot.val().Posts is like when you submit a message using the button its the value of it. I will update anwser again to tell you what that is

Comment: Ok i got it but i needed another firebase. Anways thank you for your time sir