# Angularjs:Empty value added to toDo List

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two questions.

1.In addition, the empty value gets added to toDoList.

2.On trying to add a duplicate item, it doesn't add ok. But later it also doesn't add any item further.

There is also a default item added Sample.
So I don't know how to do it.I also tried to solve the first problem by doing an empty check.But still is doesn't work.

I have not done anything with the description input so ignore it.
This is my script.js, index.htm, and style.css file.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

 $scope.item = ["Sample"];
 $scope.addTitle = function(){
    $scope.item.push($scope.addMe);
  
 };
 $scope.removeItem = function(index){
  $scope.item.splice(index,1);
 };
});
```

```css
body{
 maring:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}
.container{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.form{
 width:400px;
 height: auto;
 padding:20px;
}
.form input:nth-child(1){
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid salmon;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}
.form input:nth-of-type(2){

 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid salmon;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
 width:400px;
}

.form button{
 width:100px;
 height:40px;
 background-color: salmon;
 border:1px solid salmon;
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}
.form button:hover{
 color:salmon;
 background-color: white;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.itemList ul li{
 list-style: none;
}
.itemList ul li a{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color:red;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="App" class="container">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="form">
   <form>
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" ng-model="addMe" ng-required="true"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" ng-required="true"><br><br>
      <button ng-click="addTitle()">Add</button>
      <div class="itemList">
       <ul ng-repeat="items in item">
        <li>
         {{items}}
                  <span ng-click="removeItem($index)"><br><a href="#">Remove</a></span>
                </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat Error "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296670/angular-ng-repeat-error-duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/BassemMamar/02wu0v49/3/) from your example

1. simply because you are adding `addMe` value whatever it is, so if you want to deny empty values add that validation in your code.

> initiate `addMe` with empty string value,
>   check if current value is NOT empty before adding to `item` array

2. use `track by $index` to solve duplication issue

> for more information check this out

hope this answer your questions..

Comment: Thank you.But I don't want duplicate values for add up.It adds duplicate value also.

Comment: sorry i thought you accept duplication, any way again it's another validation ..
this is updated version  https://jsfiddle.net/BassemMamar/02wu0v49/4/

Comment: will you explain me this $scope.item.indexOf($scope.addMe) === -1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Check for *truthiness* and *length*. *i.e.* `item && item.length`

To make a model with todo items having title and description, make todo item an object with both properties.

Reset the todo model to an empty object when a item has been added.
This makes sure to update the variable reference for `$scope.todoItem` to a new object.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.todoItem = {title: '', description: ''};
  $scope.addTodoItem = function() {
    if (($scope.todoItem.title && $scope.todoItem.title.length) && ($scope.todoItem.description && $scope.todoItem.description.length)) {
      $scope.items.push($scope.todoItem);
      
      $scope.todoItem = {title: '', description: ''};
    }
    

  };
  $scope.removeTodoItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="App" class="container">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="form">
      <form novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" ng-model="todoItem.title" ng-required="true"><br><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoItem.description" name="description" placeholder="Description" ng-required="true"><br><br>
        <button ng-click="addTodoItem()">Add</button>
        <div class="itemList">
          <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
            <li>
              {{item.title}}
              <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
              <span ng-click="removeTodoItem($index)"><br><a href="#">Remove</a></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The snippet runs just fine. How doesn't it add up anything?

Comment: Sorry, You changed the variable names.I didn't notice.Thankyou.